# Why are these two functions different?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bytecode, cpython

Take a look at this:

```
>>> def f():
...     return (2+3)*4
... 
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               5 (20)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Evidently, the compiler has pre-evaluated `(2+3)*4`, which makes sense.

Now, if I simply change the order of the operands of `*`:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 4*(2+3)
... 
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 (5)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The expression is no longer fully pre-evaluated! What is the reason for this? I am using CPython 2.7.3.

Comment: Looks like a flaw in the peephole optimizer to me. You could check the bug tracker and see if it's a known problem.

Comment: Stop using old python 2.x... On 3.3 (at least) it works as it should.

Comment: @JBernardo 2.x and 3.x are very different; I cannot seamlessly switch between them.

Comment: it has 5 years already. People should start transitioning

Comment: @JBernardo: It's been far less than 5 years since critical extension modules have been ported to python 3.  For example, SciPy has only officially had support for Python 3 for 2 years.  Moving large existing codebases to a new language is expensive and takes time.  Python 2.7 is expected to remain active and viable for many years.

Comment: @JBernardo Interestingly, looks like the issue is still there in 3.1 and 3.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case the unoptimized code is `LOAD 2 LOAD 3 ADD LOAD 4 MULTIPLY` and in the second case it's `LOAD 4 LOAD 2 LOAD 3 ADD MULTIPLY`.  The pattern matcher in `fold_binops_on_constants()` must handle the first `ADD` ok (replacing `LOAD LOAD ADD` with `LOAD`) and then follows on to do the same thing to `MULTIPLY`.  In the second case by the time the `ADD` (now the second argument to `MULTIPLY` instead of the first) is turned into a constant the scanner is too far ahead to see `L L M` (when the "cursor" was on `LOAD 4` it didn't look like a `L L M` yet).

Comment: So this is a shortcoming of the compiler, then?

Comment: @arshajii: You could probably fix the bug in `peephole.c` by simply backing up one instruction after a fold.  However the right solution is to not rely on the peephole optimizer and instead fold constants in `compile.c` where it is emitting the binops in the first place.  A pass over the AST could propagate constant expression information up from the leaves and there would be no room for this kind of bug.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this issue was patched in Python 3.3, as can be seen [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue1346238).

```
>>> def f():
...     return (2+3)*4
... 
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               5 (20)
              3 RETURN_VALUE  
>>> def f():
...     return 4*(2+3)
... 
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               5 (20)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```